# Selecting non-zero minimum from the complex criteria pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I have the following dataframe:

```
Program    Version  Rand_dist_1   Rand_dist_2  Rand_dist_2    
Autocad     1.0          180        120          126
Autocad     1.1          181        125          123
Autocad     1.2          157        125          125
Autocad     2.0          220        201          173
Autocad     2.1          223        126          100
Autocad     2.3          233        334          233
Autocad     2.5          213        232          321
Autocad     3.2          424        312          312
Autocad     3.5          53         1300         112
sketchup    1.0          22          24          21
sketchup    1.3          23          22          19
sketchup    2.4          65          55          39
sketchup    3.0          32          35          33
sketchup    3.3          43          65          56
```

I have random distance variable that measures differences between the versions of softwares. How I measure is not that important I guess.
I want to compare the first versions of software that starts with 1.0, 1.1, 1.2, with the later versions. I want to find the minimum distance between the first versions and with the later versions that is not equal to zero. 
I can also compare Rand_dist_1 with Rand_dist_2 or with Rand_dist_3

The logic can be something like this:

```
Compare Autocad 1.0 version with Autocad 2.0, 2.1, 2.3, 2.5, 3.2, 3.5
Compare Autocad 1.1 version with Autocad 2.0, 2.1, 2.3, 2.5, 3.2, 3.5
Compare Autocad 1.1 version with Autocad 2.0, 2.1, 2.3, 2.5, 3.2, 3.5
(Not I am not comparing the first versions with each other)
```

Final ouput should be something like:

```
Program   Min_dist
Autocad      1
sketchup     8
```

Comment: Can you explain more fully why the expected value of `Min_dist` is 1 for Autocad and 8 for sketchup?

Comment: I think it will be better if I explain from sketchup: there are two first versions 1.0 and 1.3 and I compare this versions with newer versions. sketchup 1.0 (rand_dist_2) - sketchup 3.0 ( rand_dist_1) gives the smallest value which is 32-24

Answer (score 1):

You can use collections.Counter or groupBy class on python.

Comment: thank you for you answer but is difficult to apply when there is a complex criteria